# Variable for invoice date - Magento 2.2.6

Tags: variables, invoice-pdf

Is there a variable for the invoice date (invoice created on...) in Magento 2? I would like to add this to the standard template for invoice pdfs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

yes there is. Similar to order the invoices get a timestamp "created_at".

```
protected $order;
public function __construct(
.....
\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $order,
.......
        ) {
    ...
    $this->order = $order;
    ........
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


 public function getInvoiceDetails($order_id){

   $orderdetails = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($order_id);

    foreach ($orderdetails->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice)
        {
            $invoiceCreatedAt = $invoice->getCreatedAt();
        }
  }
```